# Is there any solution for (ActionView::TemplateError) "invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII" error in Ruby 1.9.3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encoding, ruby-1.9.3

Recently, I migrated my Ruby apps 1.8.7 to Ruby 1.9.3. After the migration, I am getting an error message called invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII. Many of them are solved by putting #encoding: utf-8 on top of the controller. But I am still getting errors on various ERB files. What is the solution for this error? My app contains Swedish Font.

Comment: You recently updated your app to Ruby 1.9.3, a Ruby version that is more than 11 years old and has dozens of [security vulnerabilities](https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-7252/product_id-12215/version_id-452263/Ruby-lang-Ruby-1.9.3.html)?

Comment: @spickermann I had to for an emergency purpose. I know it has security vulnerabilities.

Comment: What version of Rails are you using?  Do you have anything assigned to [`config.encoding`](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#config-encoding) in `config/application.rb` or anywhere else in your app?